# Uncaught ReferenceError by JS for implementing Comet

Tags: php, javascript, comet

I am trying to use comet for implementing a chat.since I didn't have any experience on comet , I searched for an example code and I found [this site](http://gonzalo123.com/2011/03/14/real-time-notifications-with-php/)

after creating all the files, I got this ambiguous error

> **Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined** (chrome console)
>   **ReferenceError: require is not defined var http = require('http');**(firefox console)

is this because I'm testing this code on a localhost server or something else is wrong?
the html code is :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Comet Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a class='customAlert' href="#">publish customAlert</a></p>
        <p><a class='customAlert2' href="#">publish customAlert2</a></p>
        <script src="http://localhost:80/chekhabara/downloads/realtime/2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost:80/chekhabara/downloads/realtime/2/NovComet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var http = require('http');

            http.createServer(function (req, res) {
              res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
              res.end('Hello World\n');
            }).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');
            console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:80/');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) code. You don't put it in an HTML file - you have to run a special node.js server.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be related to the stuff you link to.

Comment: He's trying to run a node server, that's his snippet.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: No, that's an HTML file.

Comment: no that's not a node.js I know what's node.js, I don't want to use that technology. it's jquery library NovComet.js

Comment: @weber85: Try googling `http.createServer`. What's the first page that comes up? (hint: it's node.js). Like it or not, what you've written is node.js code.

Comment: !! it's about js error and php code and comet , what else should I link???

Comment: Where did you get the line `http = require('http')` from? I don't see that anywhere on that page.

Comment: I can see it's an HTML file. The `<html>` tag gave it away ;)

Comment: @AlienWebguy: What I was trying to say was that I think the OP is also aware that it is an HTML file. Whoops.

Comment: To which the answer is: your javascript code is copied almost verbatim from the [node.js intro](http://nodejs.org/#column1).

Answer (score 0):

`require` is undefined because it's not a property of `window`.

Install [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org), put this code in a new file like `myscript.js`:

```
        var http = require('http');

        http.createServer(function (req, res) {
          res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
          res.end('Hello World\n');
        }).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');
        console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:80/');
```

and run it from the command line `% node myscript.js`.

Comment: I know how to use NodeJS, we don't want to use that technology! please do read this article!!!! http://gonzalo123.com/2011/03/14/real-time-notifications-with-php/

Comment: If you don't want to use node, remove the node code and your problem goes away, lol